# Splitting string on comma, remove the comma

Tags: python, string, split

```
tgtPorts = str(options.tgtPort).split(', ')
```

I'm trying to split a string `tgtPort` that could look like `21, 80, 139`

According to the website I was looking at, the above should split that string into a list containing each individual element IE: `139`

However using:

```
for tgtPort in tgtPorts:
    print tgtPort + "\n"
```

I find that my list *only* contains `21,`

How can I ensure that the comma and the space are removed?

How can I ensure that all elements will end up in my list and not just the first one?

Comment: Split on just the comma (not comma+space), and trim the individual strings.

Comment: Your code does not demonstrate your problem. You can see it running [here](http://repl.it/OCU). The output is `21` then a blank line then `80` then a blank line then `139` then a blank line. No commas anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spelling out Robert's advice:

```
tgtPorts = [s.strip() for s in str(options.tgtPort).split(',')]
```